# Type casting question

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

```
foreach(PlayerBase p in Members)
{
    p.Render();
}
```

The `Members` list contains members of type `FieldPlayer` or `GoalKeeper`. `FieldPlayer` and `GoalKeeper` inherit from `PlayerBase`. When I call `p.Render()`, I need the appropriate `Render` call to be called for `FieldPlayer` or `GoalKeeper`. How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You make the `PlayerBase.Render` method [`virtual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622132/what-are-virtual-methods) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You're talking about [Polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). The proper implementation of `Render` is automatically called. Make sure the Render method in your `PlayerBase` class is defined as either `abstract` or `virtual`.

Answer (score 1):

If `FieldPlayer` and `GoalKeeper` `override` the `Render` method, then this will happen automatically.

```
public abstract class PlayerBase
{
    public virtual void Render();
}

public class FieldPlayer : PlayerBase
{
    public override void Render() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `PlayerBase` is an [`interface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
public inteface IPlayerBase 
{
   void Render();
}

public class FieldPlayer : IPlayerBase
{
   public void Render()
   {
      MessageBox.Show("FieldPlayer.Render");
   }
}

public class GoalKeeper : IPlayerBase
{
   public void Render()
   {
      MessageBox.Show("GoalKeeper.Render");
   }
}
```

If `PlayerBase` is an [`abstract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class

```
public abstract class PlayerBase 
{
   public abstract void Render();
}

public class FieldPlayer : PlayerBase
{
   public override void Render()
   {
      MessageBox.Show("FieldPlayer.Render");
   }
}

public class GoalKeeper : PlayerBase
{
   public override void Render()
   {
      MessageBox.Show("GoalKeeper.Render");
   }
}
```

If `PlayerBase` is an class with a [`virtual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function

```
public class PlayerBase 
{
   public virtual void Render()
   {
      MessageBox.Show("PlayerBase.Render");
   }
}

public class FieldPlayer : PlayerBase
{
   public override void Render()
   {
      MessageBox.Show("FieldPlayer.Render");
   }
}

public class GoalKeeper : PlayerBase
{
   public override void Render()
   {
      MessageBox.Show("GoalKeeper.Render");
   }
}
```

For all three instances, the derived type's `Render` function will be called.

Answer (score 0):

If `Render` is a [virtual member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), then the method called will be that on the most derived type of the object at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `Render` on `PlayerBase` to be either `virtual` (if you have a default implementation) or `abstract`. Then, you `override` the method in the child classes with the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark `Render` as `abstract` and then every derived class must implement it.

See this for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class PlayerBase
{
    public abstract void Render();
}
```

Any class that inherits PlayerBase will be required to implement the Render function. If you have common functionality for Render, you can instead:

```
abstract class PlayerBase
{
    public virtual void Render() {
        // add common functionality
    }
}
```

Then in your sub-class, say `FieldKeeper`:

```
class FieldKeeper : PlayerBase    {
    public override void Render() {
        // add additional functionality
        base.Render();
    }
}
```