# C# redefine sub-method in child class without redefining calling method in parent class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a parent class with many methods in it that are all called by a single top-level method.

Conceptually the parent class looks like this:

```
class ParentClass
{
    void TopMethod(){ Lots of code and calls Methods1-N defined below}

    void Method1(){}
    void Method2(){}
    ...
    void MethodN(){}
}
```

I have many other classes that I want to be just minor variations on this base class.
So I declare them as inheriting from ParentClass.
Say all I need to do is change the definition of Method1 in the Child Classes.
But how do I tell the child class to use everything else from the ParentClass, just with the new definition for Method1.
In particular I don’t want the duplicate code of overriding TopMethod in the child class just so I can make it use the redefined Method1 in the child class instead of the Method1 in the ParentClass.

Comment: Well if Method1, Method2 etc are all virtual, you just override Method1 in the derived class...

Comment: You make your method virtual in parent class and override them in inherited classes wherever needed

Comment: Also consider the appropriate access modifiers on your members (methods in this case). In your example code everything is `private` by default which means a base class could not see those members (or override them). If you want access inside a derived class to a member of the base class you need `protected` at a minimum. If you want to define a new implementation it needs to also be marked as `virtual`.

Comment: See also [What are Virtual Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/622132/1260204) and [What is the difference between an abstract function and a virtual function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/391483/1260204) and [Practical usage of virtual functions in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1062102/1260204)

Comment: The post by DavidG is what I was trying to do - thanks! I was using just the "new" keyword in the child class, instead of "virtual" in the parent and "override" in the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `Method1`, `Method2` etc. virtual and override them in the child class. For example:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public void TopMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Top method in parent");
        Method1();
    }

    public virtual void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method1 in parent");
    }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public override void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method1 in child");
    }
}
```

Now calling each class:

```
var parent = new ParentClass();
var child = new ChildClass();

parent.TopMethod();
child.TopMethod();
```

Will give you this output:

```
Top method in parent
Method1 in parent
Top method in parent
Method1 in child
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: [virtual keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual)