# Scala type conversion for Any type

Tags: scala, class, oop, methods, types

This is the simple scala code.

```
val x: Int = 1000
val y: Any = x

y.toString // returns String = 1000
y.toInt // returns error: value toInt is not a member of Any
y.isInstanceof[Int] // retunrs true
```

Why `y.toInt` returns error even though `y.isInstanceof[Int]` returns true?

Comment: Because the [`Any`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Any.html) type does not have any methods called `toInt`, while it *does* have a `toString`. You can't make up method names that don't exist and expect them to work.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez This is a typical mental model of OOP newcomer that I saw before - if I see that value of of some type (since I initiated it) why doesn't compiler sees it? @Koala The answer is that compiler sees only as much as types allows it to. If `1000` is upcasted to `Any` it will see only as much as `Any` has defined. `toInt` is not defined in `Any` so it isn't seen.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```scala
class Parent {
  def parentMethod = println("parent method")
}
class Child extends Parent {
  override def parentMethod = println("parent method overriden")
  def childMethod = println("child method")
}

val p: Parent = new Child
p.isInstanceOf[Child] // true

// p.childMethod // doesn't compile
p.asInstanceOf[Child].childMethod // child method
p.parentMethod // parent method overriden
```

`p` has **static** (compile-time) type `Parent` but **dynamic** (runtime) type (class) `Child`. Which implementation of an instance ([virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622132/what-are-virtual-methods)) method is chosen is decided based on the runtime class. But whether you are allowed to call a method is decided based on the static type.